# Connecting one document to multiple documents in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

Am fairly new to Arangodb and am trying to find an example where if you are given one user{} and a list of [user{}] how can you create multiple friend edges from that one user{} to the list of [user{}] in one go. I read the documentation and there is an example for a single edge creation

```
graph.edgeCollectionName.save(from, to, data, options)
```

and am thinking of running a for loop but I have a feeling that the mutations are not batched. What would be the best way to do this?